# filereader how to get id

Tags: javascript, fileapi

I have this script:

```
$.each($(this)[0].files, function(i, file){
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#display_image').prepend("<img src='"+e.target.result+"' />");
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[count]);
        }
        count++;

});
```

so what it does is is simply gets all selected files path from `multiple input` and appends it to `img` tag.

Now what i would like to do is give that img `id` which would be equals to variable `count` but my problem is that prepending function runs after my main `each` loop is finished so i always get the same number, like `3, 3, 3` not `1, 2, 3` i guess it's happening because of `reader.onload`, but i'm not sure how to do it differently...

Comment: You need to post a little more code for us particuarily whatever this & input is(it looks like they may be synonymous) .  But at first glance you should not be using i versus count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post some more code and I can update and correct the below.  But I think you want to use `i`.

```
$.each(
   $(this)[0].files, 
   function(i, file){
      if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
         var reader = new FileReader();
         reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#display_image')
               .prepend("<img id='" i + 
                  "' src='"+e.target.result+"' />"
               );
          };
          reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
    }

});
```

Comment: Hmm i guess i could use it, it would create few other problems in my full code, but it's not hard to fix it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simples:

```
    img_id = 0;
$.each($(this)[0].files, function(i, file){
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
++img_id;
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#display_image').prepend("<img id='"+img_id+"' src='"+e.target.result+"' />");
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[count]);
        }
        count++;

});
```